# config chmod setting in mybb and joomla

Tags: linux, joomla, mybb

my question is why the my bulletin board config file must have permission 666 and do not need execute permission but joomla config file need it and must have permission 777
and here you see the recommended permission

```
Required – ./inc/settings.php – 666
Required – ./inc/config.php – 666 (install) 444 (after installation)
Required – ./cache/ – 777
Required – ./cache/themes/ – 777
Required – ./uploads/ – 777
Required – ./uploads/avatars/ – 777
Optional – ./admin/backups/ – 777
Optional – ./inc/languages/*language*/*all files*/ – 666
Optional – ./inc/languages/*language*/admin/*all files*/ – 666
```

can any one explain why permission 666 and not 644
or why permission 777?that is not a security risk
and another question is what is group exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in Joomla requires 777. In Joomla files should always be 644 and folders should be 755. The configuration.php file is the exception and should be 444.

Anyone telling you to use 777 is wrong. If you have to set anything to 777 to work, then your server is configured wrong. You are correct, that is a security issue and is definitely not recommended by Joomla.

Comment: ok that right but what about 777 permission in mybb - http://wiki.mybb.com/index.php/CHMOD_Files

Comment: It would appear that the developer(s) of mybb would rather set permissions to wide open rather than deal with the hassle of fixing user's permission problems when their servers are not set up properly. In my opinion, that's the lazy way out and should be avoided.